# How To Add A Video Background to Joomla Template

Tags: templates, video, joomla, background

I was just trying to create a video background in my joomla template. At the moment I am just modifying prostar for ease. Below is  what I have.

In the index.php I have put in a video tag below the head.

```
</head>
    <video controls autoplay muted id="bgvid">
<source src="/vid/timelapseb&w.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
<body class="site <?php echo $option
    . ' view-' . $view
    . ($layout ? ' layout-' . $layout : ' no-layout')
    . ($task ? ' task-' . $task : ' no-task')
    . ($itemid ? ' itemid-' . $itemid : '')
    . ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? ' fluid' : '');
?>">
```

In My Css file I have entered the following Beneath where the background colour style is placed

```
#bgvid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
}

video {
display: block;
}
```

I do not believe I need to include the file within the templateDetails.xml, I have tired however with no luck.

Any Ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A few things it might be...

```
<video controls autoplay muted id="bgvid">
<source src="/vid/timelapseb&w.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

should be within the `<body>` tag, not outside it.

Ampersands should not really be used in a file name.

Because of the use of base tags in Joomla, linking to a file like that may cause the link to be incorrect depending which page you are on.  Link to the root of your site using JURI instead

> <?php echo JURI::root();?>vid/timelapseb&w.mp4

If I were you, I'd first concentrate on making sure the video appears normally in the page, and then try and fiddle with the css for it to work as a background.

Finally, I believe mp4 is not supported by Opera.  You need a fallback for it to work in that browser.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's  got me off to a good start,  now I'm getting a "No video with supported format..." error, with using the fixed link and the php link. good nudge with concentrating on making it appear on the page first, Its been a long day and I was definitely over complicating ;-)

Comment: @lameki, if you're getting this error you should consider using fallback formats (OGG and WEBM) so that the video plays in browsers that don't support MP4. A simple Google search will nudge you in the correct direction for this

Comment: @Lodder,Thanks for the advice, already been using the fallback formats, but taken the code back even further purely for testing to achieve a result. Going to have another crack at it tonight, I will keep you all updated!